# SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In shellWindows returning too many objects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer, shdocvw

The following line of code return several InternetExplorer objects even though I have only one browser window open (no tabs) and only one iexplore.exe process running. How do I only get the open browser window object?

`For Each ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In shellWindows`

Comment: You will also get any open Windows Explorer window.  One thing that can work is trying to cast the ie.Document to mshtml.IHtmlDocument, that will only work for an IE instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help

```
Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim rVal As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    For Each rVal In objShellWindows
        Debug.Print TypeName(rVal.Document)
        If TypeName(rVal.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            If rVal.Name = "Windows Internet Explorer" Then
                rVal.Visible = False
                rVal.Visible = True
                Set ie = rVal
                ie.Quit
                Set ie = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next rVal
```